# Why caulking turns yellow?

Tags: caulking

I have caulking around the base of the shower and tub and it turned yellow. Is this normal? It was transparent to begin with.

[image: yellow caulking]

Comment: that is probably soap residue

Comment: Do you know what the composition of the caulk is?  100% silicone?  Or something else?

Comment: Unfortunately not, this was installed when we moved in our new apartment. @jsotola, we never use the bath. I don't think this is soap residue. 

Any suggestions as to which caulk I should use to redo the job? I'd rather have a transparent one.

Comment: Grout was probably not sealed before the silicone was put on so the grout has changed color a bit and looks yellowish under the silicone.

Comment: Sun light? Calcium, Lime, Rust, Mold, Mildew, can also discolor caulk. Apartment...you own or rent? Rent, let management know and they can fix it. Own, scrape it all off, bleach and allow to fully dry before applying new caulk or your choice.

Comment: @JeffCates I’m the owner. I will scrape it off and reapply new caulk. Any suggestions as of the brand to use? Thanks!

Comment: Brands are off-topic, but best to get a quality tub and tile/shower. One for wet surfaces.

Comment: @Jeff Cates  I think you meant to use the word "caulk" at the end of the first sentence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by one user, the grout was most likely not sealed before the silicone was put on. The grout is brownish/grey and indeed it looks like it changed color a bit and now looks yellow underneath the transparent silicone.